# Space before left tab

Tags: css, html, tabs

I have been stuck on a problem here. This is what I designed my app in html and css. The problem is indicated with red circle in lower left corner i.e. the space before the left tab. I am unable to remove this space. This is neither padding nor margin but I don't know what it is.

[image]

The code for tab is:
**html**

```
<ul id="bottomTabs">
    <li><a href="player_screen.html" class="left_tab">Player</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reciters</a></li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
ul {
    margin: 0 ;
    bottom: 0 ;
    left: 0 ;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    bottom: 0 ;
    left: 0 ;
    margin-left:1em ;
}

#bottomTabs {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: table;
    position: fixed;
    table-layout: fixed;
    text-align: center;
}

#bottomTabs li {
    width: 47.5%;
    height: auto; 
    align : center;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 1.5%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

#bottomTabs a {
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    background-color: #222;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `padding-left: 1.5%` on both of your `li` elements. You only need it for the second one. You can create a new class/id just for the second list item. Have your HTML as:

```
<ul id="bottomTabs">
    <li><a href="player_screen.html" class="left_tab">Player</a></li>
    <li id="padded"><a href="#">Reciters</a></li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
#bottomTabs li {
    width: 47.5%;
    height: auto; 
    align : center;
    display: table-cell;   
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

#padded{
 padding-left: 1.5%;   
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/cuzZC/1/

Answer (score 0):

Give a class for the first li and give padding 0..

```
.padd
{
padding:0 !important;
}

<ul id="bottomTabs">
    <li class="padd" ><a href="player_screen.html" class="left_tab">Player</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reciters</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`padding-left: 1.5%` is causing this effect.

The first li doesn't need any padding, just add

```
#bottomTabs li:first-child {
padding-left: 0;
```

}

or you could remove the `padding-left` from `#bottomTabs li` and add

```
#bottomTabs li:last-child {
padding-left: 1.5%;
```

}

I would suggest using the first-child pseudo class since it's better supported.
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
#bottomTabs li:first-child {
    width: 47.5%;
    height: auto; 
    align : center;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K9jq7/